# Python: Value from matrix based on multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python

I've been working on a problem where I have a dataframe with two columns and i'm trying to return a value based on a separate matrix.

Most things I've tried are only applicable for a single column, and involve getting into loops for more - which take all day to run.

Matrix:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA8ON.png)

df:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swvty.png)

I'm trying to make a dataframe col3 that would output "1" in row 1 and "8" in row 2.

Answer (score 0):

Let us declare your DataFrame and your matrix (assuming this is a Numpy matrix, hence indexed by integers):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['a', 'b'], "col2": ['x', 'y']})
M = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
```

One option is to first convert the letters into indices of your matrix, and then to fill the target column based on these indices and Numpy indexing:

```
df["num_col1"] = df["col1"].map(ord) - ord('a')
df["num_col2"] = df["col2"].map(ord) - ord('x')
df["result"] = M[df["num_col2"], df["num_col1"]]
df = df.drop(["num_col1", "num_col2"], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a pretty roundabout way of solving the problem. Very easy to follow the steps!